# Why is Enthalpy of Compound at Some Temperature Equal to its Enthalpy of Formation at the Same Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

This is a question I don't understand in thermo. Enthalpy of compound would be sum of U + PV at some temperature, but since we can't calculate absolute value of H, we calculate it relatively to some reference. Enthalpy of formation is heat needed to be exchanged between system and surroundings at some pressure to keep the system at the same temperature when compound is formed from elements in the most stable state. Why are these two quantities equal?

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal.  The enthalpy of a compound at temperature T is relative to the pure elements at the reference temperature $T^0$.  So it is equal to the standard heat of formation at the reference temperature plus $C_p(T-T^0)$.

Comment: So, you are saying that enthalpy of elements in their most stable form is taken as zero only at reference temperature and not the other temperatures? If so, it makes sense to me.

Comment: In practice the enthalpies of the elements are always going to cancel from any practical calculation, whether you do it this way or whether you use heats of formation at temperature T, since you are dealing with. balanced chemical reaction equations, and the elements contribute both to the products and the reactants in equal. amounts.  However, it is easier not to have to make use of the heat capacities of the elements to calculate their enthalpies at T if it is not going to matter.  Try a sample reaction both ways to satisfy yourself that this is correct.

Comment: Yes. So, do we agree that enthalpy of compound at temperature T is equal to its enthalpy of formation at the same temperature if we regard enthalpies of elements to be zero at that temperature?

Comment: I would never think of it that way.  I would always regard it as relative to a fixed specified state.

Comment: If you do it the way you are suggesting, then the simple issue of getting the change in enthalpy for heating an ideal gas at constant pressure would have to take into account the changes in enthalpy of the elements.  Otherwise, the change in enthalpy would not equal the amount of heat added.

Comment: Well, yes. Choosing enthalpies of elements to be zero is a reference since than enthalpy of formation becomes equal to enthalpy of compound because enthalpy of any reaction is stochiometric difference of enthalpies of products and reactants at constant P and T. In formation reaction reactants are elements in their most stable for which we chosen that their enthalpy is zero, so enthalpy of formation is equal to enthalpy of component at this temperature. Since formation happens at specified state (as you noted) this enthalpy is one at that specified state.

Comment: So you are in agreement now that the enthalpy at temperature T should be represented as the heat of formation at the reference temperature plus the heat capacity times the difference between T and the reference temperature?

Comment: Yes, I do agree with that. But, what I am not quite sure is that can we say that enthalpy of compound at some is T equal to its enthalpy of formation at the same T so that cp(T-T0) term becomes zero. I would say we can define reference however we want, but we should know according to what reference we calculated our enthalpy of compound.

Comment: This may be more practical if we know enthalpy of formation at some temperature closest to our working temperature since if temperature difference is small we may not need to know/take into account how cp varies with T for our compound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123725/discussion-between-dario-miric-and-chet-miller).